# Flutter Dart using too much memory during build

Tags: android, ios, flutter, memory, dart

I am developing a flutter application and sometimes dart using too much memory during build.

Installed memory is 24GB in my iMac and I am not working after I click the run button.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.16.4-pre.18, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-TR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

[image]

How can I set dart memory usage limit?

Comment: are you running your apps from the terminal or IDE (visual studio, android studio)?

Comment: I am running with my apps from android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue before and can't even build the project. But after a 
`flutter clean`, I could build it

Comment: I tried flutter clean many times but not effect on this. Dart using too much memory sometimes after a success build it is running normally but I am facing this issue still periodically.

Answer (score 0):

If run `flutter clean` doesn't work.

You can try restarting your computer. 
Or the way I did was to downgrade to a lower flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

delete unused Packages ( dependencies ) in pubspec.yaml